# Add additional nuget servers at global level

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

I have created a **dotnet new** template in the form of a nuget package and uploaded to my private nuget server. I would like to know how I could add the private nuget server at a global level on my computer. That way whenever I do a **dotnet new CustomTemplate** it would pull the latest version from the nuget server. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know how I could add the private nuget server at a global level on my computer.

[Here are the docs on where NuGet reads configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior). You can see that adding your source to `%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` on Windows, or `~/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config` on Mac or Linux should do the job.

It might be obvious, but keep in mind if you share projects that use packages from that source, then other people (including CI build agents) won't be able to restore the packages unless they also add the source to their user profile `nuget.config`, or if someone adds a `nuget.config` with the source with the repo. If you're just using it to get project templates, then it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In windows you can add NuGet config at **Network Service** level located at this path:

C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config